# Selecting patterns in character sequence using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to select all the accounts were 3 (or more) consecutive characters are identical and/or include also digits in the name, for example

```
Account
aaa12
43qas
42134dfsdd
did
```

Output

```
Account
aaa12
43qas
42134dfsdd
```

I am considering of using regex for this: [a-zA-Z]{3,} , but I am not sure of the approach. Also, this does not include the and/or condition on the digits. I would be interested in both for selecting accounts with at least one of these:

- repeated identical characters,
- numbers in the name.

Comment: Your expected output contradicts your interest `numbers at the end`

Comment: unfortunately I made a mistake in writing it. I meant including numbers in the name, not at the end. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
n = 3 #for 3 chars repeating
pat = f'([a-zA-Z])\\1{{{n-1}}}|(\\d)+' #need `{{` to pass a literal `{`
df_final = df[df.Account.str.findall(pat).astype(bool)] 

Out[101]:
      Account
0       aaa12
1       43qas
2  42134dfsdd
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
x = re.search([a-zA-Z]{3}|\d, string)
```